# how to Include the blank column to Pandas pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which has a column 'Comment' with Blank values and when i use the pivot table, the column is not available in pivot table output

`data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', 'Comment'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)`
   
 `data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`
    
`tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a!= 'All' else (a,b) for a,b in data_frame1.columns]`
   
 `data_frame1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)`

**Input Dataframe**

```
PC Geo Comp  Month          Bill1 Bill2  Comment
A  Ind   OS  01/10/2019     1     1.28      
A  Ind   OS  01/11/2019     1     1.28   
A  Ind   OS  01/12/2019     1     1.28
```

**output**

```
               OCT-19             Nov-19        Dec-19
             Bill1 Bill2      Bill1 Bill2     Bill1 Bill2     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28        1    1.28      1    1.28
```

**Desired output**

```
                   OCT-19               Nov-19           Dec-19
             Bill1 Bill2 Comment Bill1 Bill2 Comment Bill1 Bill2 Comment     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28           1    1.28            1    1.28
```

Comment: When i run your code, I get the column `comment` (filled with 0)

Comment: @SH-SF ...not a problem.. how to remove the 0's from the column Comment in the pivot table dataframe?..finally i need a blank **comment** column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working change values of `Comment` after `pivot_table`, because if use before, column is dropped:

```
data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], 
                             values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', 'Comment'], 
                             columns=['Month'], 
                             fill_value=0)

data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

mask = data_frame1.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'Comment'
data_frame1.loc[:, mask] = ''
print (data_frame1)
Month       01/10/2019               01/11/2019               01/12/2019  \
                 Bill1 Bill2 Comment      Bill1 Bill2 Comment      Bill1   
PC Geo Comp                                                                
A  Ind OS            1  1.28                  1  1.28                  1   

Month                      
            Bill2 Comment  
PC Geo Comp                
A  Ind OS    1.28
```